# Can't run webapplication on tomcat using Docker

Tags: file, tomcat, web-applications, docker, war

I am trying to show on my browser the webapp I've created for a school project.
First of all, I've put my Dockerfile and my .war file in the same folder `/home/giorgio/Documenti/dockerProject`. I've written in my Dockerfile the following:

```
# Pull base image
From tomcat:7-jre7

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "xyz <xyz@email.com">

# Copy to images tomcat path
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY file.war /home/giorgio/Documenti/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/webapps/
```

Then I've built the image with the command from the ubuntu shell:

```
docker build -t myName /home/giorgio/Documenti/dockerProjects
```

Finally, I've run on the shell:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 myName
```

Now, everything works fine and it doesn't show any errors, however when I want to reach `localhost:8080` from my browser anything shows up, nevertheless tomcat has started running perfectly fine.

Any thoughts about a poossible problem which I can't see?
Thank you!

Comment: You  mentioned a war file, but you copy a hello.py file to container. Do you want to deploy a war file?

Comment: `docker logs myName` will show you container output, perhaps an error is getting dumped there

Comment: yeah, hello.py was just a test. I edited the question. @STLMikey I will try now and then post here the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your whole Dockerfile?

Because You just remove all ROOT content (step #3)

then copy war file with your application  (step #4) - probably **wrong folder** in the question only (*should be /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*)

**But** I don't see any **endpoint or start** foreground application.

I suppose you need to add:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

and with that just run tomcat. And It is routines to `EXPOSE` port, but when you are using `-p` docker does an implicit exposing.

So your Dockerfile should looks like:

```
# Pull base image
From tomcat:7-jre7

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "xyz <xyz@email.com">

# Copy to images tomcat
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

# fixed path for copying
COPY file.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

# Routine for me - optional for your case
EXPOSE 8080

# And run tomcat
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However nothing seems to be changed. same blank page in localhost:8080

Comment: it is blank page or page not found? do you have any context in your war application? if yes you need to use localhost:8080/context

Comment: You can test: `localhost:8080/file` - the name of file should be context. or ugly solution for test purpose `COPY file.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war` and check localhost:8080